# Generate the code to create a HashTable/PSCustomObject from an existing object

Tags: powershell, hashtable, pscustomobject

I am looking for a way to generate the code to create a HashTable/PSCustomObject from a variable that already exists.

**Function Call**

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod <Parameters>...
```

**Contents of $response**

```
@{
    user = @{
        id = 123
        name = 'User 1'
        email = 'user1@test.com'
    }
    data = @{
        field1 = 'Foo'
        field2 = 'Bar'
        field3 = 'Baz'
    }
}
```

I can access all the individual elements of the HashTable e.g. $response.user.id and I can convert the whole lot to JSON to see it all, but if I want to manually re-create the `$response` variable (for example to provide different values when mocking), is there a way that I can get PowerShell to give me the code/definition to re-create the same structure?

Thanks

Comment: Propably the easiest way is to use `ConvertTo-Json` to convert to JSON string and use `ConvertFrom-Json` with a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#here-strings) to provide your mock objects in code.

Comment: @zett42's suggestion is a pragmatic alternative. If you do want to create literal source-code representations of existing hashtables / `[pscustomobject]`s, see the linked duplicates. (Note that `Invoke-RestMethod` outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances when it receives JSON data, not _hashtables_.)